# Apache not starting : no listening sockets available

Tags: moodle

I know this has been asked a few times already however, despite reading existing answers, I am still having trouble starting the Apache service from both Windows Services and XAMPP Control Panel. The error that windows returns is that there are no listening sockets available. This is despite me changing the listening socket to 7099 from port 80. Does anyone have any idea as to how to quickly and easily resolve?

enter image description here

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting everything back to default > Restart your PC to make sure that nothing else is running that might clash with XAMPP > Start xampp as administrator which allows you to start the services by clicking the ticks on the left of the service screen